# ScalaPB and shading with SBT isn't working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt-assembly, maven-shade-plugin, scalapb

I'm trying to get https://scalapb.github.io/">ScalaPB to work with Spark.  In order to do this I need to shade my protocol buffers within SBT using code like below

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.protobuf.**" -> "shadeproto.@1").inAll
)
```

This doesn't work within spark-shell.  In fact, it doesn't even work within the Scala REPL.  Reproduced below are my errors within the REPL.

```
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_102).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

  scala> val x = zefr.commons.proto.Video.VideoProto.descriptor
error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'VideoProto.class'.
Could not access term google in package com,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'VideoProto.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.
error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'VideoProto.class'.
Could not access term protobuf in value com.google,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'VideoProto.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.google.
  error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'GeneratedMessageCompanion.class'.
Could not access term google in package com,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'GeneratedMessageCompanion.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.
error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'GeneratedMessageCompanion.class'.
Could not access term protobuf in value com.google,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'GeneratedMessageCompanion.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.google.
  error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'VideoProto.class'.
Could not access term Descriptors in value com.protobuf,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'VideoProto.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.protobuf.
  error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'VideoProto.class'.
Could not access term protobuf in value com.google,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'VideoProto.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.google.
  error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'VideoProto.class'.
Could not access term google in package com,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'VideoProto.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.
error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'VideoProto.class'.
Could not access type Descriptor in value com.Descriptors,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'VideoProto.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.Descriptors.
```

Here is a fully copy of my build.sbt file

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
organization := "zefr.commons"
name := "commons-proto"


val nexus = "http://nexus.zefr.com/repository/maven"
resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
  "Neuxs Snapshots" at s"$nexus-snapshots",
  "Neuxs Releases" at s"$nexus-releases"
)
conflictManager := ConflictManager.strict

PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
  scalapb.gen() -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value
)

assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.protobuf.**" -> "shadeproto.@1").inAll
)
```

And project/protos.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "0.99.3")

libraryDependencies += "com.trueaccord.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.5.45-p3"

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

Can anyone please help me understand what I'm missing here?

Thanks

EDIT

In order to see if this was a problem that I was introducing I downloaded [this](https://github.com/thesamet/sparksql-scalapb-test) project and built it as is, only changing the Scala version to 2.11.8 and I get the same error.

```
scala> val x = com.example.protos.demo.Person.descriptor
error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Person.class'.
Could not access term google in package com,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'Person.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.
error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Person.class'.
Could not access term protobuf in value com.google,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'Person.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.google.
  error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'GeneratedMessageCompanion.class'.
Could not access term google in package com,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'GeneratedMessageCompanion.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.
error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'GeneratedMessageCompanion.class'.
Could not access term protobuf in value com.google,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'GeneratedMessageCompanion.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.google.
  error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Person.class'.
Could not access term Descriptors in value com.protobuf,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'Person.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.protobuf.
  error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Person.class'.
Could not access term protobuf in value com.google,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'Person.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.google.
  error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Person.class'.
Could not access term google in package com,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'Person.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.
error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Person.class'.
Could not access type Descriptor in value com.Descriptors,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
  missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'Person.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.Descriptors.
```

Comment: I have somewhat solved this.  It turns out I can get around the very specific problem I'm referencing above by using the Java based getDescriptor method instead of the Scala descriptor.  Everything then works fine.

I'm not giving this as an answer because it doesn't solve the entire problem I outlined above, but it'll work for those who come across this in the future.